# My information was stolen... do I have to be worried?

Tags: scams

Yesterday someone got into my steam account and stole my full address, my full name and an old phone number that is out of service. I am 17 and living in Canada and I was wondering what can happen to me?? Should I be very worried? I also lost around 300$ of items but I'm not worried about that.   The scammer also has my postal address so does that affect anything?

Comment: If that is all there is nothing to be worried about.  It used to be that one's address was listed in a phone book.  There is not much someone can do with solely a address.

Comment: Even if he has my postal code? Cant he like put my adress on some website and then dont pay the bills so that they mail them to me even tho i never bought it?

Comment: Its a duplicate but it doesnt talk about the postal code also getting stolen or is that included in the adress informations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The damage is probably not too severe (aside from the $300 lost to your Steam account.)

Signing up for credit cards (especially online) in Canada [requires more information](https://www.cibc.com/en/personal-banking/credit-cards/articles/application-tips.html) than just your address, your name and your phone number (especially an old one that's no longer in service.)  In particular, they would need at least your date of birth and your SIN, for example.  So, they can't just sign up for cards and not pay them with this info.

However, the fact that they broke into this account means they know the username and password you used here.  If you used the same password elsewhere, they may be able to break into those accounts as well, especially if the username is similar (ie: your email address.)

So, if you haven't already, you should change the password on your Steam account.  You should also go through other online accounts and change those passwords as well, particularly if they use the same password as Steam.  You may also want to consider two-factor authentication where available (ie: Steam has the Steam Guard app that can be hooked up to your account on your smartphone.)

Comment: I do have a mobile authenticator but he still got into my acc... i changed all my passwords tho and i also ran multiple scans on my pc. Thanks for all these infos tho